# How to implement RTL in iOS using EXPO/react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have added two localization file (arabic and english) in my react native application file names like **ar.json** and **en.json**.

My **en.json** file looks like

```
"fieldNames": {
    "enterEmail" : "Enter the email address"
  },
```

My **ar.json** file looks like

```
"fieldNames": {
    "enterEmail" : "أدخل عنوان البريد الإلكتروني"
  },
```

My **string/index.js** file looks like below:

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

import en from './en.json';
import ar from './ar.json';

i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { en, ar };
i18n.locale = Localization.locale;

export const string = value => i18n.t(value);

export default i18n;
```

One of the file I used like the following

```
<Text>{string('fieldNames.enterEmail')}</Text>
```

Localization is working fine with both languages.

But when I choose **arabic** its **not aligned to right side in iOS.**

In my android device its working properly.
This issue appear only in iOS .

Could you please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

**RTL is not related to Localization(l10n)**. Instead, Internalization(i18n) does.

If you use `start` and `right` prefix instead of `left` and `right`, then your RTL will be implemented.

For example, you can use `marginStart` instead of `marginLeft` for RTL